# Is my flash drive broken ? How to fix?

Tags: usb, flash, drive

I run this command "sudo tail -c 0 -f /var/log/syslog" and plug my flash drive. And this is the output :

```
May 12 20:54:09 R124L-PC kernel: [ 1658.098890] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
May 12 20:54:12 R124L-PC kernel: [ 1660.246506] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
May 12 20:54:12 R124L-PC kernel: [ 1660.383847] usb 1-1: language id specifier not provided by device, defaulting to English
May 12 20:54:12 R124L-PC kernel: [ 1660.392981] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0009, idProduct=0089
May 12 20:54:12 R124L-PC kernel: [ 1660.392995] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May 12 20:54:12 R124L-PC kernel: [ 1660.393004] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 002243908660F2A086CA0C57
May 12 20:54:12 R124L-PC kernel: [ 1660.394362] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
May 12 20:54:12 R124L-PC kernel: [ 1660.395572] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
May 12 20:54:12 R124L-PC mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1"
May 12 20:54:12 R124L-PC mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device
May 12 20:54:13 R124L-PC kernel: [ 1661.397188] scsi 5:0:0:0: scsi scan: INQUIRY result too short (5), using 36
May 12 20:54:13 R124L-PC kernel: [ 1661.397210] scsi 5:0:0:0: No Device                                        PQ: 7 ANSI: 7
May 12 20:54:13 R124L-PC kernel: [ 1661.400000] scsi 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 31
```

How to fix my flash drive ?